# Order field not available in a ListData.svc query

Tags: listdata.svc, rest

I want to query a links list using ListData.svc and have this ordered, using the query string $orderby, by Sharepoint's own internal order field.

By internal order field I specifically mean the field that is updated by the Reorder.aspx page in Sharepoint.

If I dump the entire links list by querying with ListData.svc with no options then I cannot see an order field nor anything that resembles one.

If I simply try $orderby=Order then I receive the error "No property 'Order' exists in type".

Is there a way to expose this internal order field to ListData.svc?

Comment: can you show to us an example?

Comment: Sure, [here is a pastebin of the xml output from a ListData.svc query](http://pastebin.com/Uchr3vr1), with no additional arguments, of a OOTB Sharepoint links list called "test". In the Sharepoint list the 2nd item "msn.com" is actually ordered above "ea.com" using the "change item order" feature.

Comment: did you try to "orderby" title or another column?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible to retrieve `Order` field using SharePoint 2010 REST Interface.

As an alternative approach you could leverage *SharePoint Web Services*, in particular [Lists.GetListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) to *return list items based on the specified query*

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve ordered list items using SPServices library:

```
var listName = "Links";
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    listName: listName,
    CAMLQuery: '<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Order\" /></OrderBy></Query>',
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var linkUrl = $(this).attr("ows_URL");
        console.log(linkUrl);
      });
    }
  });
```

> [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) abstracts SharePoint's Web Services
>   and makes them easier to use in JavaScript.